PV Azimuth Confusion
When I read the source code for AOI Projection it is stated that the surface panel azimuth is measured from North.
def aoi_projection(surface_tilt, surface_azimuth, solar_zenith, solar_azimuth):
    """
    Calculates the dot product of the sun position unit vector and the surface
    normal unit vector; in other words, the cosine of the angle of incidence.

    Usage note: When the sun is behind the surface the value returned is
    negative.  For many uses negative values must be set to zero.

    Input all angles in degrees.

    Parameters
    ----------
    surface_tilt : numeric
        Panel tilt from horizontal.
    surface_azimuth : numeric
        Panel azimuth from north.
    solar_zenith : numeric
        Solar zenith angle.
    solar_azimuth : numeric
        Solar azimuth angle.

    Returns
    -------
    projection : numeric
        Dot product of panel normal and solar angle.
    """

    projection = (
        tools.cosd(surface_tilt) * tools.cosd(solar_zenith) +
        tools.sind(surface_tilt) * tools.sind(solar_zenith) *
        tools.cosd(solar_azimuth - surface_azimuth))

    # GH 1185
    projection = np.clip(projection, -1, 1)

    try:
        projection.name = 'aoi_projection'
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    return projection

But when I read the NREL SPA documentation it is stated that

the surface azimuth rotation angle, measured from south to the projection of the surface normal on the horizontal plane, positive or negative if oriented west or east from south, respectively.

Which one is true or am I have a wrong interpretation of this angle? Please help me. Thank you
I tried comparing the result from PVLib and Real-Life insight. The angle is different, the pvlib yields more energy annually if the surface orient to the west while in the real life it is more if the surface oriented to the east.

There are indeed two conventions. Measuring 360 degrees clockwise from north or +-180 with south being zero. pvlib uses the former convention (north is zero) for all inputs and outputs irregardless of what the original references used.
